# Error when sending bytes through TCP: Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-integration, message-channel

I'm trying to rewrite integration.xml in an application to Java Config using DSL. My integration flow goes like this:

1. `Communication` object comes to `sendCommunication` channel
2. `sendCommunication` channel is routed into two different channels
3. objects in each channel are transformed to `byte[]`
4. data is logged with custom logger (wire tapped)
5. bytes from each channel are sent through TCP using two different `TcpSendingMessageHandler`s

Here's a part of my Integration.java related to this flow (some beans like custom logger are skipped):

```
@Bean(name = "sendCommunicationRouter")
public IntegrationFlow routeRoundRobin() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(getSendCommunication())
                           .route(roundRobinRouter, "route",
                                  s -> s.channelMapping("sendCommunication1",
                                                        "sendCommunication1")
                                        .channelMapping("sendCommunication2",
                                                        "sendCommunication2"))
                           .get();
}

@Bean(name = "sendCommunication")
public MessageChannel getSendCommunication() {
    return getDefaultMessageChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "sendCommunication1")
public MessageChannel getSendCommunication1() {
    return getDefaultMessageChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "sendCommunication2")
public MessageChannel getSendCommunication2() {
    return getDefaultMessageChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "tcpClientOutbound1")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler getTcpClientOutbound1() {
    return getDefaultTcpClientOutbound(getOutboundConnectionFactory1());
}

@Bean(name = "tcpClientOutbound2")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler getTcpClientOutbound2() {
    return getDefaultTcpClientOutbound(getOutboundConnectionFactory2());
}

private TcpSendingMessageHandler getDefaultTcpClientOutbound(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    handler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    handler.setTaskScheduler(myScheduler);
    handler.setClientMode(true);
    handler.setRetryInterval(DEFAULT_CHANNEL_RETRY_INTERVAL);
    handler.start();
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow handleOutgoingCommunication1() {
    return handleOutgoingCommunication(getSendCommunication1(), getTcpClientOutbound1());
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow handleOutgoingCommunication2() {
    return handleOutgoingCommunication(getSendCommunication2(), getTcpClientOutbound2());
}

private IntegrationFlow handleOutgoingCommunication(MessageChannel inputChannel, TcpSendingMessageHandler handler) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel)
            .<Communication, byte[]>transform(communication -> communicationTransformer.toBytes(communication))
            .wireTap(getLogger())
            .handle(handler)
            .get();
}
```

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to send data through `sendCommunication` channel (IPs hidden intentionally):

> 2016-10-09 19:52:45 WARN  TcpNetConnection:186 - Unexpected message -
>   no endpoint registered with connection interceptor:
>   **IP**:**PORT**:37007:b2347dad-b65c-4686-b016-5ef5ee613bd5 - GenericMessage [payload=byte[267], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=**PORT**,
>   ip_connectionId=**IP**:**PORT**:37007:b2347dad-b65c-4686-b016-5ef5ee613bd5,
>   ip_localInetAddress=/**LOCAL IP**, ip_address=**IP**,
>   id=c6fb70b1-6d06-a909-cfc4-4eac7c715de5, ip_hostname=**IP**,
>   timestamp=1476035565330}]

I'd kindly appreciate any help, this error is giving me a headache since yesterday. I couldn't find any explanation myself, google is giving me only [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpNetConnection.java) source code on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning that the an inbound message (reply?) was received from the server to which you sent a message, and there's no inbound channel adapter configured to handle incoming messages.

Perhaps if you show the XML you are trying to replace with Java config, someone can help.